# Sending an entire html page with phpmailer

Tags: html, css, email, phpmailer

I purchased an email template and customized it to what I want, but now I'm stuck on how to send it.

The template file is an entire html page with included fonts and even a stylesheet at the top (styletags actually, not an attached file) with mediaqueries and some font settings.

Do I send all of that? Including header tags and more? It's basically an entire html page.

How part of my emailscript is build now:

```
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$texts = 'html template';
$mail->msgHTML($texts);
```

But I haven't tested my own code yet because the template file is full of single quotes and double quotes. So the variable doesn't like that, I tried replacing all single quotes to double quotes in the templatestring but then my fonts are not working anymore (I tested remotely using this site: https://putsmail.com/).

Comment: What's your level of experience with PHP?

Comment: @hungerstar Not expert but I can understand most php. I have some experience.

Comment: @twan `$html = file_get_contents('your_template.html');` !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Thanks! How can I use variables in that external mail? Like the posted name? When I echo the variable it just shows empty in my email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMailer itself doesn't do anything special with HTML content (though `msgHTML` reads your content to make a rough plain-text version). It sounds like you're just having trouble quoting inline content. You might like to try a different form of quoting called [`nowdoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) which will tolerate all kinds of quotes without a problem:

```
$texts = <<<'EOT'
html template
EOT;
$mail->msgHTML($texts);
```

You could also save it in an external file and read it in when you need it, which also avoids quoting issues:

```
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('template.html'));
```

Comment: Great, that works! But how can I use variables like $name (in which the name is posted)? I assume echoeing it into the external file is not going to work.

Comment: Just use a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead. Variable interpolation is the main difference between heredoc and nowdoc. You can have PHP values in external files rendered by using `include`, but by that point you're probably better off looking at a templating language to handle it better.

Comment: hmm never heard of that before, I have to read some more about it to understand.

Comment: Note that the `EOT` string can be any string that is unlikely to appear in your text, it's just a way of marking the end of the text unambiguously - there nothing special about "EOT" - I think it's a vague reference to "end of text" or something.

Comment: What you are talking about is ways of using variables in a string right? What I mean is the data from the form is posted to mail_send.php in which the email template is loaded with file_get_contents, but the posted data is not directly accesible by that template file, so I'm trying to understand how to display the posted data inside the template layout.

Comment: That's a separate problem, but as I said if you use `include`, the template will be treated as PHP and have access to your local vars, so you would need to do pull the submitted data into local vars (like `$name = $_POST['name']`), then `<?php echo $name; ?>` instead of just `$name` in your template. You should apply validation and sanitising to any user-submitted data before using it. Template engines like Smarty and Twig add lots of abilities beyond this.